# PHP object-oriented multiple insert values to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, oop, foreach, insert-update

I am building a lightweight school management system, that takes in grades directly from the database, how do I update all values at the same time. Please help

```
<?php 
$mydb->setQuery("SELECT * FROM tblbible");
loadresult();   

function loadresult(){
    global $mydb;
    $cur = $mydb->loadResultList();
    foreach ($cur as $result) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td> <input type="hidden" name="studentID" value="'. $result->studentID.'" /></td>';
    ?>
    <?php

    $rowz = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblstudent where studentID = '$result->studentID' ")or die(mysql_error());
    $detailz = mysql_fetch_array($rowz);
    echo '<td>'.$detailz['name'].' '.$detailz['initial'].' '.$detailz['lastname'].'</td>';
?>

<?php
echo '<td> <select name="studentID[]" class="form-control" required>
                            <option>Select Grade</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            </select></td>'; 
echo '<td> <select name="studentID[]" class="form-control" required>
                            <option>Select Grade</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            </select></td>'; 
echo '<td> <select name="studentID[]" class="form-control" required>
                            <option>Select Grade</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            </select></td>'; 


?>
<?php
echo '</tr>';
} 
?>
```

then the insert function below:

```
<?php 

function doInsert(){


if (isset($_POST['save'])){

    if ($_POST['value1'] == "" OR $_POST['value2'] == "" OR $_POST['value3'] == "") {
        $messageStats = false;
        message("All fields are required!","alert alert-success alert-dismissable");
        redirect('index.php?page=5');
    }else{

    $studentID = $_POST['studentID'];

         for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++) {

          foreach( ($studentID) as $key => $value ) :
            $cla = new Bible();     

        $value1         = $_POST['value1'];
        $value2         = $_POST['value2'];
        $value3         = $_POST['value3'];
        $cla->sing                  =$value1;   
        $cla->verses                =$value2;
        $cla->prayer                =$value3;   

    $cla->update($studentID);

    redirect('index.php?page=5');
    message("Report generated successfully!", "info");  

    endforeach;
        }
    }
}
}
```

And I would love to add all those in a one click button.

Comment: plz dont use mysql functions as [they are being deprecated as of PHP5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: please suggest a better method to use

Comment: This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the MySQL API Overview for further help while choosing a MySQL API.